# bash script works in CLI but fails in systemctl service

Tags: linux, systemctl

I'm no linux expert but I'm trying to learn.

I wrote a simple bash script to run my vpn connection automatically upon start up.

```
#!/bin/bash
cyberghostvpn --country-code PL --connect
```

I works fine when I run it through my CLI

```
sudo ./cyberghostvpn-launcher.sh
```

I tried to wrap it in a service like this :

```
[Unit]
Description=VPN start
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/xxxx/Documents/cyberghostvpn-launcher.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I ran the enable command (OK)

`$ sudo systemctl enable vpn-launch.service`

But I get an error when trying to start the service :

```
julien@uproxy:~$ sudo systemctl status vpn-launch.service                                                                            
× vpn-launch.service - VPN start
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vpn-launch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2024-03-31 17:00:12 UTC; 16s ago
    Process: 95180 ExecStart=/home/julien/Documents/cyberghostvpn-launcher.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 95180 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 173ms

Mar 31 17:00:13 uproxy cyberghostvpn-launcher.sh[95182]:   File "cyberghostvpn.py", line 6, in <module>
Mar 31 17:00:13 uproxy cyberghostvpn-launcher.sh[95182]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
Mar 31 17:00:13 uproxy cyberghostvpn-launcher.sh[95182]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Mar 31 17:00:13 uproxy cyberghostvpn-launcher.sh[95182]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
Mar 31 17:00:13 uproxy cyberghostvpn-launcher.sh[95182]:   File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
Mar 31 17:00:13 uproxy cyberghostvpn-launcher.sh[95182]:   File "configs/base.py", line 3, in <module>
Mar 31 17:00:13 uproxy cyberghostvpn-launcher.sh[95182]:   File "configs/base.py", line 12, in BaseConfiguration
Mar 31 17:00:13 uproxy cyberghostvpn-launcher.sh[95182]: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
Mar 31 17:00:13 uproxy cyberghostvpn-launcher.sh[95182]: [95182] Failed to execute script 'cyberghostvpn' due to unhandled exception!
Mar 31 17:00:12 uproxy systemd[1]: vpn-launch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I can't understand what's wrong.
Any ideas folks?

thanks for your lightings

Comment: That's a Python error, not a bash error. We'd need to see the Python script that bash is starting, and the full stack trace (if the script hides the rest of the trace and only prints the one line of error output you showed us, I'd tend to argue that that's a bug, or at least malpractice on the part of its authors).

Comment: That said, I wouldn't be at all surprised if the Python script was trying to use an environment variable that was only set when running in your interactive shell.

Comment: A human who sees a script named `cyberghostvpn-launcher.sh` is being perfectly reasonable if they execute it as `sh cyberghostvpn-launcer.sh`, and is quite reasonable when they file a bug when it fails on a syntax error due to a bashism.  This will not happen in your case, as the script has no bashisms, but the point remains.  Do not name your bash script with a suffix that implies it is not a bash script.  In fact, don't use a suffix at all. 
 https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/